# Cross-platform C++ Directory Managing

Tags: c++, cross-platform, directory

Are there any cross platform libraries that will help me place certain file in different directories. For example in windows a config file will probably go in app data, yet in Linux it will go in /etc/ or /use/etc/ depending on where it was installed. Is there any way to do this transparently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/index.htm) will should [soon provide such functionalities](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2010/10/172361.php) (but not yet). I would be you, I'd use boost::filesystem and provide different addresses of user folders by platforms, then when boost::filesystem provide the feature, replace the implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with Qt libraries?

Both `QFileInfo( qApp->argv()[0]  )::absFilePath ()`
and `QApplication::applicationDirPath()`  can work.

Comment: Ive come across it a bit, but due to the license and size of the Qt library. I would prefer something small, that I can legally, compile static. It also doesn't seem to be quite what I'm looking for. I want the config dirs, and so on, dynamic to where it was compiled, such as /, /opt or /use